# uncaught TypeError datepicker is not a function in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```
<script>
    $('#datepickerCls').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
</script>
```

I am using jquery datepicker in my wordpress site it gives an error that datepicker is not a function, i already use JQuery instead of $ but still not working.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Is the datepicker plugin included?

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the scripts before the call?

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```